# Mongoose doesn't create TTL indexes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my Mongoose model:

```
var sessionSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
    expire: { type: Date, index: { expireAfterSeconds: 21600 } }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Session', sessionSchema)
```

I need to be able to set a date object into expire (usually it's something like `Date.now` plus a few minutes) and have the object removed from the collection after 6 hours past the expiration.

However, I'm not able to have Mongoose to create the index. When I run `db.sessions.getIndexes()` in the mongo console, here's the output:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "dev.sessions"
    }
]
```

I've tried also with different syntaxes, like 
`expire: { type: Date, expires: 21600 }` (Mongoose's short-hand version).
I tried also defining the index at the schema level:
`sessionSchema.index({ expire: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 21600 })`
None is working.

Unlike others who asked questions on SO, my index is simply not created. I've tried also removing the collection and the database as well, and when they're recreated they still don't contain the index.

Versions: Mongoose 3.8.19, MongoDB 2.6.5 (OSX) and Node.js 0.10.33

#### Edit

More info: I tried creating the index directly from the mongo console, with:
`db.sessions.ensureIndex({"expire":1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 21600})`
That appears to be working (the index is created).

However, it's not working with Mongoose in any way.

Comment: I've a feeling this is a bug with Mongoose. Filed https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2459

Comment: I am actually interested in knowing if this works, running into the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that I created an index on the custom `_id` field. MongoDB creates an index on that field by itself, so when Mongoose was calling `ensureIndex` to create also the TTL index, it failed for both.

See https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2459